# Apple TV airplay Stuttering on Yosemite

Tags: appletv, macos

I just upgraded to Yosemite today and found that mirroring my laptop to my apple TV is very stuttery... It's not lagging but every second there's a slight delay, both audio and video.

Anybody else encounter this? I was messing with my router a bit today unfortunately so I'm not sure if this is a Yosemite issue or not...

Anyone know what I can try to fix it?

Edit: MBPr Late 2013, ATV 3

Comment: Might it be possible your AppleTV is on wifi and your network is under stress due to downloads and updates?

Comment: No nothing all good there but it's not like it's lagging it's a very regular delay which is strange...

Comment: It might be due to the change the way AirPlay works in iOS 8 and Yosemite, by adding peer-to-peer, the same protocol which it used in AirDrop to share files.

Comment: Any idea what I could try to fix it?

Comment: Nope, when I do, I'll post it as an answer. Sorry.

Comment: This is not a problem with Early 2011 MBA & ATV 3.

Answer (score 4):

A possible workaround for the airplay/wifi issues is to use the following terminal command

`sudo ifconfig awdl0 down`

This will disable AWDL & Airdrop but will allow you to have bluetooth on with airplay...

`sudo ifconfig awdl0 up`

will re-enable.

Credit to Mario Ciabarra who detailed the problem and solution in his [blog post](https://medium.com/@mariociabarra/wifried-ios-8-wifi-performance-issues-3029a164ce94).

Another workaround that may be of benefit to some is to make sure ATV software is up to date, and then switch off bluetooth while using Airplay. This resolves the problem for me.

Also, I seem to get best results when in extended desktop mode instead of mirrored although I haven't tested it really. This was definitely the case in Mavericks.

Hope that helps!